# How to implement the ddply of plyr package code to dplyr of the following cabbage_exp data set. Any help would be appriciated

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

```
### This is a R related problem.
### I'm using windows 10
### Latest R version and Packages

library(plyr)

library(dplyr)

library(gcookbook)
```

In **gcookbook** library there is a data set called **cabbage_exp**. In this data set I would like to calculate the **proportion of weight** within each group(**grouped by Date**).

In my data set 6 samples are there and each sample contains date and weight.
there are 3 dates d16, d20 and d21 and each date row has a weight value. So my goal is to group the data by date and calculate the relative proportion weight. For example the group would be (d16, d16), (d20, d20) and (d21, d21) and the relative proportion of weight withing each group should be added up-to 100. Say d16 = 40% and d16 = 60% so the group total =100% and so on.

The following code of **plyr** package splitting on "Date" and compute weight proportion in each group. It is working like a charm but I am trying to implement this same code using **dplyr** package but not getting the same result

```
library(plyr)
ddply(cabbage_exp, "Date", transform,
      percent_weight = Weight / (Weight)*100)
```

[Final Result of ddply (click here to see the image of plyr code results)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSMn6.jpg)

I'm using the following code with dplyr but getting ungrouped proportion which is not date wise grouped proportion

```
library(dplyr)
cabbage_exp %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  mutate(percent = Weight/sum(Weight))
```

[Final result of dplyr code (click here to see the dplyr code results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EyJN.jpg)

### Question.

How to implement dplyr code to get the same result. I have tried with the group_by but it isn't grouping the Date together. Any help in this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ungroup` function.

```
cabbage_exp %>% 
    group_by(Date) %>% 
    mutate(Wt = sum(Weight)) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    mutate(percent_weight = Weight / Wt * 100) %>%
    arrange(Date) %>% 
    dplyr::select(-Wt)
```

Produces the following output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  Cultivar   Date Weight        sd     n         se percent_weight
    <fctr> <fctr>  <dbl>     <dbl> <int>      <dbl>          <dbl>
1      c39    d16   3.18 0.9566144    10 0.30250803       58.45588
2      c52    d16   2.26 0.4452215    10 0.14079141       41.54412
3      c39    d20   2.80 0.2788867    10 0.08819171       47.37733
4      c52    d20   3.11 0.7908505    10 0.25008887       52.62267
5      c39    d21   2.74 0.9834181    10 0.31098410       65.08314
6      c52    d21   1.47 0.2110819    10 0.06674995       34.91686
```

Comment: That is what the code I provided does. You may want to run it and compare it to the `plyr` results that you stated were desired. I added a sort by date and removed the intermediate term.

Comment: you may want to check what you've coded - I edited my answer to show the  results.

Comment: Thanks you sir, your answer is 100 % correct. May be there is a problem withing my code. Thanks for giving your precious time.

Comment: I have restarted my R Now it showing the same results. Thanks a lot sir.